# What is the default password for MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I run

```
mysqladmin5 -u root -p ping
```

I get a password request.

I found the [following instructions](http://209.85.135.132/search?q=cache:dOuYx3bOSvsJ:bugs.mysql.com/39208+site:mysql.com+password+8.41&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=fi&lr=lang_en) but they seem to be rather brutal

```
<<
After installing MySQL 5 on Solaris with pkgadd you will have to perform
the following post-installation tasks:
As root:
# rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/mysql
Then as mysql:
$ cd /opt/mysql/mysql
$ scripts/mysql_install_db
Then as root:
# /etc/init.d/mysql start
Then as mysql:
$ /opt/mysql/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root password 'password'
Then as root:
# /opt/mysql/mysql/bin/mysql_secure_installation
>>
```

The password was not blank as in some versions of MySQL.

[*Thank you for pointing that out!*](https://serverfault.com/questions/35863/what-is-the-default-password-for-mysql/35864#35864)
The version of my MySQL seems to be

```
mysql5 --version     
mysql5  Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.83, for apple-darwin9.7.0 (i386) using readline 6.0
```

**What is the default password of the MySQL?**

Comment: mysqladmin is at version 8.41, not MySQL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the -p.  That is making it prompt you for a password.

http://linux.die.net/man/1/mysqladmin

Answer (score 2):

The default password depends on the distribution, I think. In some Linux distributions you're asked to enter pass during installation, in other it's blank for connection over loopback.

Try starting MySQL with the [--skip-grant-tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-grant-tables) option, then logon with the MySQL command line and [change root's password](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-password.html).

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! --- I fixed my mistake.

Comment: I guess he is using mysqladmin 8.41 on MySQL5.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql -p ping
```

is very different from

```
mysql --password=ping
```

first one means "Connect to database and prompt for password", second one means, "Connect to database with password 'ping'"